# How to solve dependency conflict between different python packages?

Tags: python, tensorflow

Recently, I want to perform some reinforcement learning tasks. Thus, I was trying to install "Stable Baselines". However, when I use this library, I find that I must install TensorFlow 1.0 to make it work. An unfortunate thing is that I rely on some packages which need to use TensorFlow 2.0. Thus, I cannot find a good way to solve the conflict between two packages unless I modify the source code of one package. Therefore, is there any possible way to solve this problem?

(Someone mentioned the virtual environment. However, I do not think it will work because I need to use those two packages simultaneously. Thus, there will also be a conflict in the virtual environment.)

Comment: create a virtual environment for your application. Install the required packages in that environment.

Comment: In practical its difficult to use two different Tensorflow versions in single environment. When we install new Tensorflow version, it will overwrite the existing version. Its better to make source code compatible to one package. Here is the [guide](https://www.tensorflow.org/guide/migrate) to migrate your code from Tensorflow 1.x to Tensorflow 2.x.